# How can I find a null field efficiently using index

Tags: postgresql

I have a query where I'm trying to find a null field from millions of records. There will only be one or two.

The query looks like this:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM “table” 
WHERE “id” = $1 
AND “end_time” IS NULL  
ORDER BY “start_time” DESC LIMIT 1
```

How can I make this query more performant eg using indexes in the database.

Comment: try a partial index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try a partial index, smth like:

```
create index iname on "table" (id, start_time) where end_time is null;
```

Comment: I believe a partial composite index with `id, start_time`  will be better to also help with the sorting

Comment: ah - with start_time! yes makes mucch sense - thanks. and again :) if OP has several nulls in end_time - sorting start_time wont take long for two rows

Comment: ya this is what I ended up doing. worked like a charm